Aplication of Duhamel's Principle with heat equation with Dirichlet conditions in an unhomogeneus problem
I am working on solving the following problem:
\begin{align*}
&u_{t} = k u_{xx} + h(x, t), \quad x > 0, \; t > 0, \\
&u(0, t) = 0, \quad t > 0, \\
&u(x, 0) = 0, \quad x > 0,
\end{align*}
where $ h $ is a smooth function with $ h(0, t) = 0 $ for all $ t > 0 $.
Using Duhamel’s Principle, I obtain the following solution:
\begin{equation}
u(x, t) = \int_0^t \widetilde{h}(x, s) \star H(x, t - s) \, ds,
\end{equation}
where $ \widetilde{h}(x, t) $ is the odd extension of $ h $.
However, when I attempt to verify this expression, I encounter the following problem:
\begin{equation}
u_t(x, t) = \widetilde{h}(x, t) \star H(x, 0) - \widetilde{h}(x, 0) \star H(x, t) + \int_0^t \frac{d}{dt} \widetilde{h}(x, s) \star H(x, t - s) \, ds.
\end{equation}
If $ \widetilde{h}(x, 0) \star H(x, t) = 0 $, my verification is complete, but I am unsure why this term would vanish. Could anyone provide insight into why this might occur?

Leibniz rule says $$\frac{du}{dt} = [ \bar{h}(x, t) \star H(x, t - t) ] \frac{d}{dt}(t) - [ \bar{h}(x, 0) \star H(x, t - 0) ] \color{red}{\frac{d}{dt}(0)} + \int_{0}^{t} \dots$$
